# How to stop audio on jQuery mouseleave()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a bit of code served by javascriptkit.com which dynamically create an audio element and load a given source file. I modified it a bit to set a loop attribute then play continuously on jQuery mouseenter(). This all works properly.

I added a function stopSound and jQuery mouseleave() to trigger that stop method, but the audio continues to play without the mouse on the element. The console does not show any errors, yet it fails.

**Here is the code**

```
jQuery(function($) {

// Mouseover/ Click sound effect- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
// Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for full source code
// http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/soundlink.shtml

var mimetype = { 
    "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
    "mp4": "audio/mp4",
    "ogg": "audio/ogg",
    "wav": "audio/wav"
}

function soundFx(sound='')
{
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    if (audioElement.canPlayType)
    { 
        for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
        {
            var src = document.createElement('source');
            src.setAttribute('src', arguments[i]);
            if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                src.setAttribute('type', mimetype[RegExp.$1]);
            audioElement.appendChild(src);
        }

        audioElement.playsoundFx = function(){
            audioElement.setAttribute('loop','loop');
            audioElement.play();
        }

        // this added method does not execute
        audioElement.stopSound = function() {
            audioElement.pause();
            audioElement.currentTime = 0;
        }

        return audioElement;
    }
    else{
        return {playsoundFx:function(){
            throw new Error("Your browser does not support HTML5 audio");
            }
        }
    }
}

// sound fx trigger
$.fn.runsoundFx = function(soundfile='') {
    this.mouseenter(function() {
        soundFx(soundfile).playsoundFx();
    });
    this.mouseleave(function() {
        soundFx().stopSound();
    });
};

});
```

What do I need to do in the code to get the audio to stop on mouseleave?

---

**Update 9/26**

The code now works with the checked solution provided by @PatrickEvans , be sure to read his response as I've left the original question intact.

If anyone wants to use it in a document, the methods to attach sound to an element by ID, class or element name are:

```
$("#myelement").runsoundFx("/url/to/file.mp3");
```

or attach to all images

```
$("img").runsoundFx("/url/to/file.mp3");
```

or attach same audio to multiple classes and/or IDs and element names

```
$(".myclass, .otherclass, #myId, strong").runsoundFx("/url/to/file.mp3");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soundFx()` is going to create and return a new audio instance when it is called. It is not going to return the instance created in a previous call. You will need to modify your code to keep track of your sound instances, test to see if it was already created returning it if so, otherwise create it and add it to the tracker.

For instance you could make a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) list using the source url as a key.

```
var audioMap = new Map();

function soundFx(sound='') {
  if(audioMap.has(sound)){
    return audioMap.get(sound); 
  }

  //rest of your creation code

  //add instance to map before returning it
  audioMap.set(sound,audioElement);
  return audioElement;
}
```

And in your mouseleave pass in your source value

```
$.fn.runsoundFx = function(soundfile='') {
    this.mouseenter(function() {
        soundFx(soundfile).playsoundFx();
    });
    this.mouseleave(function() {
        soundFx(soundfile).stopSound();
    });
};
```